# Tag request [PS2EXE-GUI]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

Would it be possible to request the tag `PS2EXE-GUI` to be created/added?

`PS2EXE-GUI` relates to PowerShell, but in particular, [PS2EXE-GUI-Convert](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/PS2EXE-GUI-Convert-e7cb69d5). I've noticed a few tickets being raised with PowerShell issues, but in particular, focus on the issues after using the tool.

What are your opinions?

Edit: Question examples:

[Error "Cannot find path from" during program start up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59247846/error-cannot-find-path-from-during-program-start-up)

[Convert PowerShell script to exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48338017/convert-powershell-script-to-exe)

[Possible to constrain form data powershell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45572950/possible-to-constrain-form-data-powershell)

[prevent a form closing with $Form.Close() returning "Cancel"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43211375/prevent-a-form-closing-with-form-close-returning-cancel)

[Modify Application GUI interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58992714/modify-application-gui-interface)

Comment: @SamuelLiew I would say it didn't take long - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59285526/convert-multiple-poweshell-scripts-into-an-exe-file - likelihood is we'll continue to get similar questions going forward where normally they'd have simply used the one which is closed.

Comment: Reopened, for this one time only. I can't guarantee it stay open though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added [ps2exe-gui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ps2exe-gui) as well as a simple [tag excerpt and description](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ps2exe-gui/info). Feel free to improve.

Tagged two questions with the new tag.